# Critical thinking problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So here is a question which I extracted from my 11 years old brother.

Previous Year:

The number of student of $x$ school is less than $y$ school for 60 people.

This Year:

The number of student of both schools increases by 22 people. The number of student of $y$ school is double of $x$ school.

So, what is the number of students in $y$ school at the previous year?

Comment: Try to write down two equations using $x$ and $y$, and see if you can use them to solve.

Answer (score 1):

Solve the following system of $2$ equations in $2$ variables:

- $x+60=y$
- $2(x+22)=y+22$

Comment: Assuming that your 11 years old brother got it as homework assignment at school, he should be able (or learn how) to solve this type of systems.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose school $x$ had somehow managed to find another $60$ students last year, so it would be equal to school $y$.  This year, each school would add another $22$ students, and they would still be equal.  Those $60$ students are the difference between being the same size as school $y$ and being half that size this year.  So school $y$ must have $120$ students this year.  Last year, school $y$ had $120 - 22 = 98$ students, and school $x$ (without those fictional $60$ extras) had $98 - 60 = 38$ students.

Answer (score 0):

Let, the number of students in school $X$ is $N$.

So, the number of students in the school  $Y$  is  $N+60$ , because the number of students in school $Y$ is $60$ more than that of $X$.

And this year the number of students in both school is increased by $22$ so the number of students in school $X$ is $N+22$ , and the number of students in the school $Y$ is [$N+60+22$ = $N+82$] .

And this year the number of students in school $Y$ is double than the number of students in school $Y$ so,

$$2(N+22)=(N+82)$$ $$=>2N+44=N+82$$ $$=>2N-N=82-44$$ $$=>N=38$$

So the number of students in school $Y$ at the previous year is $N+60=38+60=98$